# How to have response model personalized which include a status code and a StreamingResponse on FastAPI?

Tags: python, response, fastapi

I want my post request response on this format, I'm using FastAPI:

```
{
  "message": "",
  "status": 200,
  "data": {}
}
```

So I declare a class to specify my response format and send this model in the response_model parameter. The thing is that in my case data key is a CSV file that's why on post request I have this:

```
@app.post('/some-path', response_model = ResponseBase)
async def some_path():
    ....

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(final_data, columns=header)
    stream = io.StringIO()
    new_df.to_csv(stream, index=False)
    my_data: Response = StreamingResponse(
        iter([stream.getvalue()]), media_type="text/csv"
    )

    return ResponseBase(
        message="Some message",
        status = status.HTTP_200_OK,
        data = my_data
    )
```

Response model class, should be something like this:

```
class ResponseBase(BaseModel):
    message: str
    status: 
    data:
```

But I wonder how to specify that status comes from HTTP status code module and data comes from StreamingResponse class.

Comment: You can't both respond with a content-disposition header and assume that you're delivering a CSV file _and_ have a JSON body; those two won't work together as you're trying - exactly which goal are you trying to reach?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I don't have a reason to do that, I just wondered if that would be possible.

Comment: @MatsLindh, what if I don't implement content-disposition header, can I specify that status comes from HTTP status code module and data comes from StreamingResponse class and how?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I mean is there a way in which I define data attribute as Streaming Response type, in order to match `data = my_data`

Comment: What would that do? What are you trying to achieve? Since a `StreamingResponse` is a hint to FastAPI that it should serve the content of the response as it becomes available, having it inside another response won't work, since the response returned to FastAPI is a structure that has a specific form (i.e. a JSON entry)

Comment: @MatsLindh, For instance, if I need a response model class, containing a message, status, metadata and data attributes, since I can't have a file attached in data attribute, a solution could be to send the file to a file server something like IPFS and just add the URL returned into the data attribute for fetching the file.

Comment: You don't need `StreamingResponse` for  that, though? You can return that as a normal response from your API without wrapping it in a `StreamingResponse`. I'd also argue that there is no need for a specific `status_code` field in your response, as the HTTP response code is already included for any response being sent back. To get the relevant data (I'd also suggest making explicit models that represent your information, not just `data`), you resolve any iterators or coroutines (await) and then return the response.

Comment: @MatsLindh, it just that I realized my solution afterwards, in first instance I was not going to use a file server. By the way, thanks for suggestions.